# REGEX python multi selection from multi line text

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to return each of the sections between "RECT"

```
RECT  
texttextetxtsd  
text  
texttexttexttext  
RECT  
texttextetxtwes  
text  
texttexttexttext  
text  
MMMM  

Such that I get 

[texttextetxtsd  
text  
texttexttext  
text,  
texttextetxtwes  
text  
texttexttexttext  
text]
```

I try `re.findall(r"RECT(.*(?:\n(?!MMMM).*)*)", text)`

But I get everything after the first RECT lines

Any help searching and returning the text between the RECT as elements in an array.  Python 3.6.1

Comment: With `RECT.*(?\n(?!MMMM).*)*=+`, you can't get anything, it is an invalid pattern. What is your pattern?

Comment: Try `(?m)^RECT[ \t]*((?:\n(?!RECT\s*$|MMMM).*)*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/DVEQo2/1

Comment: I typed in my pattern wrong. I am using:  RECT(.*(?:\n(?!MMMM).*)*)

Comment: Ok, but you only restricted matching lines starting with `MMMM`. The lines that start with `RECT` are still consumed with the `\n(?!MMMM).*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "tempered" the `\n.*` pattern with the `(?!MMMM)` negative lookahead and restricted it to matching lines that do not start with `MMMM`, those starting with `RECT` are still consumed. You need to add `RECT` as an alternative:

```py
re.findall(r"RECT(.*(?:\n(?!MMMM|RECT).*)*)", text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DVEQo2/2).

A bit more precise pattern would be

```py
re.findall(r'^RECT[ \t]*((?:\n(?!RECT\s*$|MMMM).*)*)', text, re.M)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DVEQo2/3). `^` matches the start of a line (due to `re.M`) and `$` matches end of a line.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `RECT` - a `RECT` word
- `[ \t]*` - zero or more spaces/tabs
- `((?:\n(?!RECT\s*$|MMMM).*)*)` - Group 1: zero or more occurrences of

  - `\n(?!RECT\s*$|MMMM)` - an LF char not followed with `RECT` and then zero or more whitespaces till end of line or `MMMM`
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.